# DataGridCell edit mode issue in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, mouseevent, wpf-4.0, datagridcell

Here is the problem:

When we want to edit a `DataGridCell`, we have to select the `DataGridRow` at first. I mean for editing a `DataGridCell` outside the `DataGridRow.Current`, we need to 1. `Click` the cell to select row, 2. `DoubleClick` the cell to go to edit mode. My question is how can we go to edit mode just with a single click? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can set the `SelectionUnit="Cell"`, was selected to only one `Cell`.

Second, you can start editing with key `F2`.

To start editing when you click on a `Cell`, you need to add the following event handler `GotFocus`:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" SelectionUnit="Cell" GotFocus="MyDataGrid_GotFocus" ...>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void MyDataGrid_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(DataGridCell))
    {            
        DataGrid MyDataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

        if ((MyDataGrid != null) && (MyDataGrid.IsReadOnly == false))
        {
            MyDataGrid.BeginEdit(e);
        }
    }
}
```